# Why doesn’t my login condition work?

Tags: objective-c

im making a simple log in system but it won't work... why?

```
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender {
    if (username.text == @"Username") {
        …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comparing strings using `==` does not do what you think it does, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293859). Just to sum up:

```
NSString *foo1 = @"foo";
NSString *foo2 = @"foo";
NSString *foo3 = [NSString stringWithString:@"foo"];

foo1 != foo3 // pointer equality
[foo1 isEqual:foo3] // object equality
[foo1 isEqualToString:foo3] // same results as isEqual:, a bit faster
foo1 == foo2 // string literals are optimized to have the same address
```