# Why my if condition goes the wrong way

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking for equality in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293859/checking-for-equality-in-objective-c)

I have following codes:

```
    NSLog(@"Before, let's see what is in itemTitleField: %@", self.itemTitleField.text);
    NSLog(@"And the item title was: %@",self.item.title);
    if (self.itemTitleField.text == @"test") {
        NSLog(@"Look, I've got the new title: %@",self.itemTitleField.text);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No the item title was different: %@", self.itemTitleField.text);
    }
```

And when I check the log it was displayed as following:

```
2013-02-04 09:59:03.308 Test[1275:11303] Before, let's see what is in itemTitleField: test
2013-02-04 09:59:03.309 Test[1275:11303] And the item title was: test
2013-02-04 09:59:03.309 Test[1275:11303] No the item title was different: test
```

I was expecting:

```
Look, I've got the new title: test
```

Comment: You cannot use the `==` operator to compare objective-c objects unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the if statement, you need to use  isEqualToString function:

```
if([self.itemTitleField.text isEqualToString:@"test"])
```

Comment: Dhruv Goel is right. self.itemTitleField.text == @"test" compares the actual objects and so the newly created string @"test" is not the same object self.itemTitleField.text (you can print their memory location and you'll find that they are different). However, isEqualToString:@"test" compares the content of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use isEqualToString instead of "==":
     if ([self.itemTitleField.text isEqualToString:@"test")) {