# iOS if else statement not working

Tags: ios, if-statement

I have two string. This strings is not equal but if else statement always saying yes.

My code these;

```
 PFQuery *bilquery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Bildirim"];
    PFObject *saat = [bilquery getObjectWithId:@"lQTsXaBvuq"];
    NSString *asd = [saat objectForKey:@"gun"]; //asd is 06 or 07.

    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
    int d = [dateString intValue] + 1;
    NSString *dplus1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",d];
    if ((dateString = asd)) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else {
       NSLog(@"NO");
       // Bla bla bla

    }
```

NSString asd in my parse database.
Where is my correct in if else statement?

Comment: You need to step back and learn the basics of the language. The `=` operator is the assignment operator. To compare two objects you need to use the `isEqual:` method. In the case of two `NSString` objects, use `isEqualToString:`.

Comment: @Salieh - Once your question has been answered, please do not delete or overwrite your questions with "Thanks" commentary as anyone else coming to find an answer to a similar issue will not see your original question.

Comment: @Tommy I suggested an edit to restore the original content, but moderators say that is inappropriate, so it seems it's fine if Salieh does what he did.

Comment: @Sancho - I rolled the question back to its previous form.  I was brought here by reviewing proposed edits.  Thanks for the catch, I believe it should be left in its original form as you proposed

Comment: ah. Thank you for rolling back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking for equality in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293859/checking-for-equality-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((dateString = asd))
```

Here you are assigning `asd` to `dateString`, as you use a single `=`.
Comparisons are made with `==`.

But as `NSString` instances are pointers, you can't use `==` to compare the string values.
Use:

```
if( [ str1 isEqualToString: str2 ] )
```

That being said, I think you should really take some time to learn some Objective-C basics...

Answer (score 1):

`=` is not the operator for testing equality.

`==` tests for equality, but since you're using pointers, this still wouldn't be correct.

See this answer for more detail ([Checking for equality in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293859/checking-for-equality-in-objective-c)), but you need to use this test:

`if([dateString isEqualToString:asd])`