# iOS 64 Bit Count

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In this UITable methode I get the number of sections in my table:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.myMutableDictonary allKeys] count];
}
```

Everything works fine on 64 Bit devices and simulator. But on older devices/simulators my table shows 0 sections or 1 section (random). However there should be 15 sections like in the 64 Bit Versions.

I know it has to be something with 64/32 Bit, but I have no idea what the reason is.

Comment: Most likely that's just coincidence. I don't see how that could be caused by differences in 32/64 bit architectures. How do you create myMutableDictionary? Btw. `allKeys` is unordered. It's not a good idea to use that as dataSource.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing in the above code that would be sensitive to integer size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. You were right, it has nothing to do with count.

I compared NSDates in my app with the '<' sign. Apparently this is possible with 64 Bit devices and provides good results. However with 32 Bit devices it provides random results.

Now I use the
    - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate
methode. Everything works fine

Comment: I would revisit the logic of comparing `NSDate` objects with `<` on 64 bit architectures. I would start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2293878/620197)

Comment: You can't (validly) compare NSDate objects with `<` or `==` or such.  When you do that you're comparing object addresses, and even if two NSDate objects are identical they likely have different addresses.  (It *might* work on a 64-bit system *sometimes* because NSDate and NSNumber objects are *sometimes* optimized into single 64-bit quantities.  But you can't bet on this, even from one execution of your code to the next.)

Comment: (You should NEVER use those operators to compare objects.)